# What particular actions/request caused spikes on the CPU?

Tags: cpu-usage, windows-server

While running a load test using Visual Studio 2013, I’ve noticed some spikes in the CPU due to SQL Server Windows NT on the DB machine and IIS Worker Process on the web server. Both processes used around 98% of CPU.

Is there a way to track what specific requests/particular actions caused the spikes? For example what action from the application made the IIS Worker process to use that percentage of CPU?